# Change the background of a table row onClick

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclick

I have a table in Android Studio and when I click on a cell, it should turn green, or any other color, that is not important, but I don't know how to implement that.
I only have the xml file now and I am unsure what to add exactly and where.
It's the first time when I try to implement something like that and I don't know where I should start from or what I need for that.

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/blank"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <TableRow

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000">

        </TableRow>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000"

        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=" Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=" Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=" Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=" Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=" Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=" Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

Could someone help, please?
Many many thanks.

Comment: We expect you to make an honest attempt at a solution, post that attempt, and then ask specific questions about it (i.e. explain why it didn't work or what the problem with it is).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is useful for you to insert an EditText tag in every row so you can turn its color as you want like `"editTextVar.setBackground('some-color-code')".`

I hope the best try for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use it:

```
your_object.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_colorID_in_colors));
```

Or it(System colors):

```
your_object.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```